# Wrong device resolution on AIR simulator in Flash builder

Tags: air, flash-builder

I have such a problem: I'm writing application for Android using Adobe AIR 2.6 and Flash Builder 4.5. I need to scale my resources depending on mobile device resolution. For this purpose I need to know device resolution and DPI. I'm using such a code to get it:

```
PlatformUtil.init(mainView.stage.stageWidth, mainView.stage.stageHeight, 
                Capabilities.screenDPI, mainView);
```

When I run this code on device - all OK! All resources scaled properly (on Nexus One).
But when I run it on my desctop computer on flash builder simulator, and choose from devices Google Nexus One - it must have resolution 800*480, but in code I get actual size 500*375.
When I'm using Capabilities class, it returns me 1024*768 (my desctop resolution).
So, whats wrong with it? Why it returns me wrong device resolution? How can I solve this problem?
Thanx for help.

Comment: I checked: air simulator returns resolution 500*375 for ALL Android devices, but each of them has different real resolution.((

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this issue. Simulator returns valid simulator screen resolution in handler on Event.RESIZE, this can be done like this:

```
public class Main extends Sprite
    {       
        public function Main()
        {
            super();

            //register to add to stage
            this.stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResize);
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

            // support autoOrients
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        }

        private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
        {
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }

        private function onResize(event:Event):void
        {
            this.stage.removeEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResize);

            //width must be bigger then height, because we in landscape mode
            var w:int = Math.max(this.stage.stageWidth, this.stage.stageHeight);
            var h:int = Math.min(this.stage.stageWidth, this.stage.stageHeight);

            //draw black background
            with( graphics ) 
            {
                beginFill(0x0)
                drawRect(0,0,w,h);
            }

            init();
        }
}
```

Hope it will help someone like me.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are always seeing 500x375 as your width and height is because those are the default values of the `mxmlc` compiler (specifically the `-default-size` option). See here for details :

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_13.html

Unless you know the actual dimension of the mobile device ahead of time (which is unlikely), you have to wait for `Event.RESIZE` to fire before fetching `stage.stageHeight`. You should listen to `Event.RESIZE` on the `stage` object.